# Why HttpWebResponse.ContentLength returns -1 all of a sudden?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebresponse, http-content-length

We have a peculiar issue here.
We have a code on the client side to download some files from the web server using HTTPWebResponse/HttpWebRequest 
We are using `HttpWebResponse.ContentLength` to get the size of the file...
All these days it was working fine but suddenly it started giving -1
However when we bypass the load balancer on the server it works..
Can anyone please give a fair idea on why this might be happening

Answer (score 2):

`HttpWebResponse.ContentLength` just reports what the server sends in the `Content-Length` header. Or, it might report -1 if the server didn't send anything.

Whatever the problem is, it's with the server, not with `HttpWebResponse`.

Since you said that the problem goes away if you disable the load balancer, I would suspect that at least one of the servers that gets activated by the load balancer isn't setting the header.

Comment: Thank you Jim! I use this content length to get the size of the file to update the progress bar accordingly.. however the file gets downloaded.. so i am getting a response from the server..

Comment: Yes, the server is sending a response, but not setting the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: is there something i need to look into IIS for fixing this?

Comment: @Sathish: I'm no IIS expert, so I don't have any specifics for you. You might search for [IIS content-length load balancer] and see what comes up. Or post a question on superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN's documentation on the [`HttpWebResponse.ContentLength` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentlength.aspx):

> If the Content-Length header is not set in the response, ContentLength is set to the value -1.

Simply put -- the server is not sending the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Hi Donut.. but the server is sending the response... in my case i am able to download the file from the sever.. but only the Content-Length property returns -1

Comment: @Sathish I understand that the body of the response is being sent, but the `Content-Length` header is different (and that's what's not being sent by the server).

Comment: So how should i fix this.. is there something i need to check on the server side or IIS settings